# How to separate two users in the firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my application, I have two users--Event Member and Client--they have separate user login and registration. If a client log in he will go to the the client activity; if an event member will log in he will go to the event member activity. How will I make sure that the email is a client or an event member?

Below image shows my firebase structure:

[image]

Here is my code:
SignupClient.java

```
      signupClient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String cemail = clie_email.getText().toString().trim();
            final String cpassword = clie_password.getText().toString().trim();

            String ccpassword = clie_cpassword.getText().toString().trim();

            final String cfname = clie_firstname.getText().toString().trim();
            final String clname = clie_lastname.getText().toString().trim();
            final String cbday = clie_birthday.getText().toString().trim();
            final String ccountry = clie_country.getSelectedItem().toString();
            final String cmobile = clie_mobile.getText().toString().trim();

            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(cemail, cpassword)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(_5_SignupClient.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                            Toast.makeText(_5_SignupClient.this, "createUserWithEmail: onComplete" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(_5_SignupClient.this, "Authentication Failed" + task.getException(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                AccountInfo accountInfo = new AccountInfo(cfname, clname, cemail, cpassword, cbday, ccountry, cmobile);
                                mDatabaseReference.child("client").push().setValue(accountInfo);
                                startActivity(new Intent(_5_SignupClient.this, _7_ViewClient.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

LoginClient.java

```
         loginClient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String clie_unameemail = clie_emailuname.getText().toString();
            final String clie_pass = clie_password.getText().toString();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(clie_unameemail)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(clie_pass)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }



            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(clie_unameemail, clie_pass)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(_3_LoginClient.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                           mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                                    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    if (user != null) {
                                        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("client");

                                        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                                    if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(snapshot.getKey())){
                                                        startActivity(new Intent(_3_LoginClient.this, _7_ViewClient.class));
                                                    }
                                                }
                                             //   startActivity(new Intent(_3_LoginClient.this, Normal_memberActivity.class));
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                            }
                                        });

                                    } else {
                                        // User is signed out
                                    }
                                    // ...
                                }
                            };

                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // there was an error
                                if (clie_pass.length() < 8) {
                                    clie_password.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(_3_LoginClient.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(_3_LoginClient.this, "Successfully Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(_3_LoginClient.this, _7_ViewClient.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

I hope you could help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your db there should be **one more field** like we say it **USER_TYPE**. While registering the user send its USER_TYPE. suppose if you are registering a user as a **CLIENT** then inser db value **USER_TYPE="CLIENT"**  and if its as an Event member registration then inser db value **USER_TYPE="EVENT"** and now once you **logged in check its USER_TYPE** and **redirect** him based upon his **USER_TYPE**

Comment: How will I check the user type in the log in? Can I have some syntax? Thanks!

Comment: You have to change your db structure. Just create only one user node and which have user childs either he is event user or either he is client user. Both will be under user node.so you can check it easily...